# Why python subprocess command is getting [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ls': 'ls' while executing using through API call

Tags: python, flash, subprocess, gunicorn

I am running a simple `subprocess` command by calling an API developed with Flask that is exposed using Gunicorn, and no matter what the command is I get the error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

**Code example**

```
from .. import app
from flask import request, jsonify
import logging
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from subprocess import check_output

def get_shell_script_output_using_communicate():
    session = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
    if stderr:
        raise Exception("Error "+str(stderr))
    return stdout.decode('utf-8')


@app.route("/api/start_command", methods=['POST'])
def start_command():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/import.log', level=logging.INFO)
    out = get_shell_script_output_using_communicate()
    logging.info("{} {} {} ".format(datetime.now(), "command finished", out))
```

While of course, the expected output would be to log the `ls` command result.

I can run the same command without any problem in a (let me say) *non web service* mode.
I have also tried all different versions of subprocess calls with and without `shell=True`. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to run subprocess in a gunicorn-flask program?

Comment: You might need an absolute path, e.g. `/bin/ls` ?

Comment: Yes it was the absolute path! Does that mean that all env variableas aren't loaded? I need to run some external command lines that works only of a list of PATH variables are set... What's the best way to do this?